# Can I only pull the date from SVN Keyword $Date$

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm just learning about SVN as I work with it for a large project update and bumped into SVN keywords.

In the past, the company has been manually entering in a new copyright year if they edit the script. The copyright remained untouched for scripts which were not modified.

This got me to thinking, "hey, I see that SVN keywords automatically update when you update a file on the repository. That's what we need for the copyright statement since we only modify the copyright statement if we have made changes to the script."

Is there a way we can have SVN automatically pull just the year and edit our copyright statement each time we check in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you want to accomplish exactly with [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). I'm not a lawyer but I don't think it makes much sense to have a different copyright year on each file if they belong to the same project. And updating a single global copyright year at once is trivial with almost any editor (not to mention that it only happens once a year).

In any case, since the year at `$Date$` comes first:

```
$Date: 2017-03-11 17:27:37 +0100 (sá., 11 mar. 2017) $
```

... you can truncate the tag with the fixed-length keyword syntax:

```
Copyright (c) $Date:: 2017#$ by Acme Inc.
```

Since this is far from looking nice, you may want to give custom keywords a try, despite not actually being powerful at all:

```
$Copyright:: (c) 2017#$ by Acme Inc.
```

To define this custom `Copyright` property you'll need to use the *Advanced* dialogue:

[image: Properties dialogue]

The aforementioned example is accomplished with:

```
Copyright=(c)%_%d
```

Comment: You know, I'm not entirely sure as to why they don't want to change the copyright of every single file either, but this is what I wanted so thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

SVN client leaves the keyword name in place when it expands the keyword. However, I guess that you could write a script that would reformat the expanded keyword.

Don't miss the documentation -- [SVNBook | Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).